# how to convert nested for loop in stream API for the program

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

```
List<Emp> list = Arrays.asList(
                   new Emp(123, "ABC"), new Emp(123, "BCD"), new Emp(1243, "AUBC"), 
                   new Emp(1233, "ABEC"), new Emp(1233, "ABLC")
                 );
List<Emp> listNew = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    for (Emp emp : list) {
        if (list.get(i).getCommitId() == emp.getCommitId() && (!list.get(i).getHost().equals(emp.getHost()))) {
            Emp emp1 = new Emp();
            emp1.setCommitId(list.get(i).getCommitId());
            emp1.setHost(list.get(i).getHost());
            listNew.add(emp1);
        }
    }
}
```

I just need to compare two commitid if both are same and host will be different then return those data in the form of list of emp.

Comment: Could you add the expected output to your question? Also, for completeness specify which argument of `Emp` is the commit id and which one is the host.

Comment: What is the goal of that , that is unclear for me, what is the requirement of that code ?

Comment: What if you had three `Emp` objects with say commit id `123`? How many should be in the final list? Please add a sample input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a predicate to filter the `Emp` with the same commit id and a different host, filter the stream and collect to a new list

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Emp> list = Arrays.asList(new Emp(123, "ABC"), new Emp(123, "BCD"),
            new Emp(1243, "AUBC"), new Emp(1233, "ABEC"), new Emp(1233, "ABLC"));


    Predicate<Emp> sameCommitIdWithDifferentHost = (Emp emp) -> list.stream()
            .anyMatch(l -> l.getCommitId() == emp.getCommitId() &&
                    (!l.getHost().equals(emp.getHost())));

    List<Emp> listNew = list.stream().filter(sameCommitIdWithDifferentHost).collect(Collectors.toList());

 
}
```